# Coefficients of a minimal polynomial are homogeneous polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

If we have an endomorphism $\varphi$ in a $n$-dimensional vector space, and the expression of his characteristic polynomial $P_{\varphi}(X)$ is as follows :
\begin{equation}
P_{\varphi}(X)= X^n + \alpha_1X^{n-1} + \dots + \alpha_{n-1}X + \alpha_n
\end{equation}
then, we know the $\alpha_i$'s are all homogeneous polynomials of degree $i$ of the coefficients of the matrix representation of $\varphi$.
We also know that the minimal polynomial $\mu_\varphi$ of $\varphi$ divides $P_\varphi(X)$.

My question is : does the coefficients of $\mu_\varphi$ also follows the same rules as the characteristic polynomials? i.e. if we have
\begin{equation}
\mu_\varphi(X)= X^r + \beta_1X^{r-1} + \dots + \beta_{r-1}X + \beta_{r}
\end{equation}

Are the $\beta_i$'s homogeneous polynomials of degree $i$ of the coefficients of the matrix representation of $\varphi$ ? If yes, how do we find that ?

Answer (score 4):

No: indeed the $\beta_i$ are not even continuous functions of those coefficients, essentially because $r$ itself is not a continuous function of those coefficients. Consider for example the family of matrices
$$\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}1&t\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\colon t\in\Bbb R\bigg\}.$$
Here the minimal polynomial is $X^2-2X+1$ for all $t\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, but $X-1$ for $t=0$.

Comment: I was asking about the form : in your case, when $t \neq 0$, $\beta_1 = -2$ which is a homogeneous polynomial of  degree 1 of the coefficients of the matrix and when $t = 0$, $\beta_1 = -1$ and it is still the case.

Comment: If you allow your polynomial to depend arbitrarily on one of the coefficients of the matrix, then being homogeneous—indeed, being a polynomial—ceases to have any meaning. Perhaps you should clarify exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I think I can't be any more clearer than I already am but i'll try : If we take an arbitrary example, it is always the case (We can see it with your example.) \\
But is it always the case in the general case, i.e : if we take a matrix $(a_{ij})$, $i,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$  and if  

$\mu_{\phi} = X^r - \beta_1X^{r-1} + \dots + \beta_{r}$ is the minimal polynomial of that matrix, do we have $\beta_k=P_k(a_{ij})$ for all $k$ (with $P_k(X_1,X_2,...)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$ )?

Answer (score -1):

Let $t$ be trancendental/indeterminate.

Then 
$$
\mu_{t\phi}(X)\ |\ \mu_{\phi}(tX)\ |\ \mu_{t\phi}(X)
$$
and so these minimal polynomials are equal.

Now this gives us the characteristic property of homogeneity:
$$
\beta_j(t a_{11}, \dots, t a_{nn})=t^j\beta_j( a_{11}, \dots,  a_{nn})
$$
where the $a_{ij}$ are the matrix entries.

Comment: Can you please develop a little bit please? how do we get $\mu_{t \phi}(X) | \mu_{\phi}(tX)$ and so on ?

Comment: We observe that $\mu_{\phi}(tX)$ kills $t\phi$ to get the first divisibility. Then we use it with the replacements $t\to \frac{1}{t}$, $\phi\to t\phi$, $X\to tX$ to get the second.